# Split the My Account WooCommerce tabbed menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, woocommerce, account

How to split the "My Account" WooCommerce tabbed menu in three different sections.

Here is the current code that I got:

```
<nav class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_menu_items() as $endpoint => $label ) : ?>
            <li class="<?php echo wc_get_account_menu_item_classes( $endpoint ); ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( $endpoint ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**What I need:** I have a total 15 menu items to split this way:

- I want to wrap first 5 items in first `<ul>`
- then 4 items in second `<ul>`
- and rest in third `<ul>`

Please help me how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy adding a counter that will add `</ul><ul>` after the 5th and the 9th menu items. See below:

```
<nav class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation">
    <ul>
        <?php
            $count = 0; // Initializing the count variable
            foreach ( wc_get_account_menu_items() as $endpoint => $label ) :
        ?>
            <li class="<?php echo wc_get_account_menu_item_classes( $endpoint ); ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( $endpoint ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php
            $count++; // increasing count
            if($count == 5 || $count == 9 ) echo '</ul><ul>'; // Adding <ul>
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow, that was awesome. it worked very well. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate.